# django cms: template for placeholder

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Placeholder : packages_details_header

1. Banner
2. static block (where we add the text in textarea and convert it into html at time of render)
3. two label
4. label for heading

But as per the html wrappers and css classes, I think it is difficult to implement above structure

So my suggestion is

can we have pre defined template for placeholder?

Where all above listed plugins are predefined in placeholder template, like as shown in following example

```
{% block content %}
    {% placeholder "packagesdetailscontent" %}
        <div class=”banner”> banner plugin </div>
        <div class=”static”> Static plugin </div>
        ..
        ..
        ..
        <h2> label plugin</h2>

    {% endplaceholder "packagesdetailscontent"  %}
{% endblock content %}`
```

Please let me know, if there is any solution on it

thanks,

B

Answer (score 1):

You can limit plugins allowed in a placeholder using CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF

See http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf

---

**Update:**

I read your question again, if I understand it correctly.. you are struggling with wrapping plugin with html class?

Have you had a look at https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style

It would allow you wrap your existing plugin in whatever classes you need :-)

Comment: Yes! I think your suggestion is good. I can manipulate the placeholder content on `post_save` signal. But can you explain above code  explain block?

Comment: Ideally you should use `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` to pre define plugins for a given placeholder.

Comment: well I will have look at it and let you if it fits for my needs or not